# Parser Error on user control after deploying and while adding on web part page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I created a user control for sharepoint 2007 site on my test server it was working properly. and today I deployed it on production It is giving parser error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'EditSkillNew.EditSkill'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditSkill.ascx.cs" Inherits="EditSkillNew.EditSkill" %>

Line 2:

Line 3:      .style1

Source File: /_controltemplates/MySkill/EditSkill.ascx    Line: 1

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.832; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.832 
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

We might need some more information to solve this, but there are a few things you could check.

- Is there anything in the Event Log that might help?
- Is the assembly containing your control signed? If so, your `Inherits` attribute would need to look something like `Inherits="EditSkillNew.EditSkill, EditSkill, Version=a.b.c.d, Culture=someculture, PublicKeyToken=xyzabc"`
- Are there any configuration differences between your test and production environments?
- Are you deploying to the GAC?